# powershell to export list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell

Please provide me powershell script to export the list from one web application to another web application. Only list structure need to copy like list name, columns etc not data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Powerhell code for exporting a list without contents.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "SiteUrl"
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$list.SaveAsTemplate("File_Name.stp", "List_Template_Title", 
"Description", $false);
```

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but is `false` something in PowerShell? I would expect `$false`

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. You are right. It should be $false

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Great. Have my upvote :)  (I usually don't care, but perhaps `$web.Dispose()`?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SPList.SaveAsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.saveastemplate.aspx) cmdlet for that.

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPList oList = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["Site_Name"].Lists["List_Title"];
oList.SaveAsTemplate("File_Name.stp", "List_Template_Title", 
"Description", true);
```

Then upload the template file into your destination site's template gallery and you should be able to create a list from it.

Or, if you'd like to preserve all the content versions and permissions, you can use [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx).

```
Export-SPWeb http://youSPSite/ -path ”D:\backup\Documents.cmp” -ItemUrl /Documents -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity
```

**edit - I now see that my first code is c#. Crappy morning today, please have a look at Nadeem's code below to see the same method used in PowerShell

Comment: Http://yoursite( here i have to post site url or list url?)
Itemurl( what i need to put here?)

Comment: the url points to your site/web and the itemurl is a relative url to your list. Please have a look at the documentation that I provided.